# android Draw Text with text size change and translate in canvas

Tags: java, android, canvas, paint

I want to draw text on canvas and that text will be scalable and translate.
I am trying below code, but didn't get any success.

```
if (paint == textPaint) {
    textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    textPaint.setTextSize(30);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 10, 20, textPaint);
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

I need to draw text using path , because i am creating one paint library with draw rectangle, cloud , line etc in single canvas, and also remove that shape.

I need to store paths in `ArrayList` and remove that path when click on undo.

Comment: see `Canvas#scale()` and `Canvas#translate()` methods

Comment: its not working on when creating all shape.

Comment: `Canvas#scale()` and `Canvas#translate()` are working - i used them in many places without any problems

Comment: I want to change text size of that already drawn text on canvas

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.graphics.Canvas&method=translate and https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/android.graphics.Canvas/translate for example

Comment: how to change text size after draw text on canvas android

Comment: i have no idea what you mean

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190491/discussion-between-dipali-and-pskink).

Comment: Let's discuss in chat.